# Transaction present on server in Never call

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm using hibernate 4 version. Trying to persist an entity using the following   code:

```
    if(surveyUserRequestTO!=null){
        surveyUser = new SurveyUser();

        surveyUser.setAdmin(surveyUserRequestTO.getAdmin());
        surveyOrganization = getEntityManager().find(SurveyOrg.class, surveyUserRequestTO.getOrganizationID());
        if(surveyOrganization !=null){
            surveyUser.setSurveyOrg(surveyOrganization);
        }else{
            return null;
        }
        surveyUser.setUserName(surveyUserRequestTO.getUserName());
        surveyUser.setUserSurveyID(surveyUserRequestTO.getSurveyUserID());

        getEntityManager().persist(surveyUser);
```

And I'm getting following exception:-

```
JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component NewUserDataProvider for
 method public
 com.alt.survey.user.transport.output.SurveyUserResponseTO
 com.alt.survey.user.dataprovider.NewUserDataProvider.createNewUser(com.alt.survey.user.transport.input.SurveyUserRequestTO)
 throws java.lang.Exception: javax.ejb.EJBException: Transaction
 present on server in Never call (EJB3 13.6.2.6)
```

What I believe it's something related to TransactionAttribute property. Any possible help will be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have NEVER transaction attribute somewhere in your code (see your stacktrace). You can not start transaction inside EJB method with NEVER transaction attribute

Comment: I want to be sure, can't we start transaction inside ejb method with NEVER transaction attribute or client to that method is required to call without a transaction?